# react native null is not an object modal

Tags: react-native, expo

Why I get this error ?

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'modalSuccess.open')
```

code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import { updateVerified, toastShown } from '../redux/slice/authSlice';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import { ModalCollectionSuccess } from '../components/modal/successCollection/ModalCollectionSuccess';

const Profile = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

  let modalSuccess = useRef(null).current;

  const handleNavigateToAuthRegister = isUser => {
    navigation.navigate('AuthRegister', {
      isUser
    });
  };

  const handleSetToastToFalse = () => {
    Toast.hide();
    dispatch(toastShown({user}))
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    user.showCollectionSuccess === true && modalSuccess.open();
  }, [user.showCollectionSuccess]);


  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <StatusBar color="#fff" />
      <Toast style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2}} ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
      <Portal>
          <ModalCollectionSuccess ref={el => (modalSuccess = el)} />
        </Portal>
    </View>
  )
};


export default Profile;
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: let modalSuccess = useRef(null).current; You don't need `.current`. `let modalSuccess = useRef(null);`  You have used `modalSuccess.open()` but what is that function open()? All you have is NULL.

Comment: To open a model from this libary: https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize

Comment: Check their sample and your sample. You are using useRef in the wrong way.